# KVM main output display shakes when mouse attached

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

My brand new display works fine when connected directly to a computer or even with the KVM switch while no mouse is attached. Oddly enough the wireless keyboard works fine.

As soon as I attach the wireless mouse the screen flickers. But if I switch which computers output I show through the KVM switch it works fine. This has led me to think it is my other computer (Computer 2)

This computer is a little older hardware, but running windows 7 like computer 1.
The wireless mouse and keyboard (Seperate units with seperate receivers) have both had the latest drivers installed on each computer. I have also checked through the device manager computer 2's drivers for the screen and output.

As soon as I unplug the mouse the flickering stops, but that then means I will have to have two mice which the kvm switch is trying to avoid! P.s this also happens when I plug in a wired mouse.

Can anyone think of anything I should try to resolve this?

EDIT:
OK I have solved this issue. I lowered the screen resolution to match computer 1 and the flickering stopped. Now the issue I would like to solve is. When when increasing the resolution of the screen above 1024 does the new monitor flicker?